# Cauchy theorem not inside and simply connected

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

I begin in complex analysis. I have the following formulation for the Cauchy integral:

If $\gamma$ is the boundary of a compact $K$ (not reduced to a single point) included in an open set $D$ of the complex plane and $f$ a holomorphic function on $D$.
Then
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0 \qquad (1)
$$
Moreover if $a$ is inside $K$, we have
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)dz}{z-a} = 2i\pi f(a).
$$

Ok. Now if I add the assumption that $D$ is simply connected and $a$ is not inside $K$ then since $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ is holomorphic on $K$ and the integral of the form $\frac{f(z)dz}{z-a}$ along $\gamma$ is equal to the integral along any homotopic curve to $\gamma$. Hence :
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)dz}{z-a} = 0.
$$

Can you confirm me that we need the simply connected assumption  to have this result ?

edit: I think I don't need the simply connected assumption in this case since I can just apply the Cauchy theorem (equation $(1)$) to the holomorphic function $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ on $D\setminus \{a\}$, the compact being $K$ not containing $a$ and its boundary is the closed curve $\gamma$. I conclude it is zero.

Comment: Your first  statement is false if $K$ is a  singleton.

Comment: Is gamma a simple closed curve, is K a topological disk?

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. Why would the integral be $0$ if you apply Caucgy's theorem to $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ and $D\setminus\{a\}$?

Comment: But the fact that the first integral equals 2pi i f(a) seems to indicate that K cannot be random. In other words, your set of conditions on K seems insufficient to imply that the first integral take the value you indicate.

Comment: humm ok. I work with the course of Cartan available here :
https://b-ok.cc/book/845983/465fe4
(see page 75, theorem 5)
Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Hey, French book! OK there, Cartan forgot to explicitly state that K is a compact bounded by finitely many simple closed curves (see pages 65-66). In particular : the boundary of K is not one but *several* curves.

Comment: Oh thanks, no it's my fault I didn't see this assumption $\gamma'(t)\neq 0$ in these pages to have a simple curve !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve then $K$ is a topological disk and $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point by a homotopy staying in $K$. In particular, if $a$ does not belong to $K$ the second integral is $0$, whatever $D$ is.

Comment: Ok I understand why I need simple closed. But I can't remove this assumption applying again the Cauchy theorem for the function $f(z)/(z-a)$ ?